# ifconfig, ethernet device name too long and get truncated, how do I know the actual name?

Tags: opensuse, ifconfig

I'm trying openSUSE 13.1 x86, but immediately encounter an annoying problem. In this openSUSE version, compared to 12.2, `ifconfig` does not show network device name as eth0, eth1 etc, but use a strangely long name, such as eno167777... , however, it does not show it in its full length(truncated to max 9 chars). If I'm not able know the full name, I will not be able to use `vconfig` to create a VLAN on it.

Please help.

[image]

Comment: Try running `ip addr list`, and see if the full name is shown

Comment: Great tip, you can write it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ip addr list` should show all network interfaces without being truncated